# How to apply condition for built in validators

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have some requirements to check when user is creating a new issue. So on creation if they select particular component say "ABC", then duedate should be a mandatory field and if they forget to add that then it should throw an error. And the duedate should always be greater than 3 weeks than the today's date, if not it should display an error and until unless it's greater than 3 weeks they can not create issue.

I did see some inbuilt validators for required fields and duedate but it's applying to all component whereas I need only for particular component. Any suggestion/help ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Script runner Plugin, This can be achieved by writing a custom behavior.
For example Script runner Behavior:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserUtil
import  java.util.Date.*

def componentField= getFieldByName("component/s")
def dueDate= getFieldByName("Due Date")

dueDate.setRequired(false)

dueDateValue = dueDate.getValue() as Date
def today = new Date()

def threeWeekDate= today.plus(21)
if (componentField.getValue() == "ABC") {
     dueDate.setRequired(true)
}
if(dueDateValue.before(threeWeekDate)){
       dueDate.setError("You must choose a date after 3 weeks from today")
  }
```

Comment: Hey Madhumitha,

Thanks for the help!